# Find the point on a curve which is closest to a given point

Tags: matlab, distance, point

[image]

I have a curve cutting through my mesh in 2D. It is a moving to the front with time. I have set of points on this curve (front) and my nodes on the mesh. At each time step I need to find which point on the curve (front) is closest to the nodes on my mesh. In other words for each node in my mesh I would like to know which point on the curve is closest to it. Is there a built in MATLAB function to search for this ? (I am using MATLAB environment)

In the figure the question would be which one is the closest black circle to any of the yellow squares.

Comment: Can you give some example code so we know what your variables look like?

Comment: @Lisa, I basically have the coordinates of black circles (nX2) matrix and coordinates of yellow squares (mX2) matrix. At the end I expect to get a matrix of size (mX2) that contains for each yellow square (m of them) the coordinates of closest black circle (1X2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://statinfer.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/efficient-matlab-i-pairwise-distances/) is an efficient function to calculate pairwise distances:

```
function D = sqDistance(X, Y)
    D = bsxfun(@plus,dot(X,X,1)',dot(Y,Y,1))-2*(X'*Y);
end
```

Assuming `circles` are the coordinates of the black circles and `squares` the coordinates of the yellow squares as you described, you can do the following:

```
% example matrices
circles = rand(5,2);
squares = rand(8,2);

D = sqDistance(squares', circles');    
[~,idx] = sort(D, 2)

closest_points = circles(idx(:,1),:)
```

`closest_points` has the same dimension as `squares` and stores the coordinates of the closest circle for every yellow square.

Comment: thanks a lot working perfectly fine. i also found this built in function in MATLAB **[k,d] = dsearchn(PInterface,X) ** that gives the distance d and the index of the closest circle k :)